# increase size of array

Tags: c, memory-management, sum, malloc, realloc

May you help me with this exercise please?

> Write a C program that reads 6 integers from the keyboard and assigns the first 5 values at the first 5 positions of an array; store the sixth value in a variable N. Write a function that, given input the array initialized with the first 5 values from the keyboard and the integer N, returns the array resized to contain 5 + N elements, such that each one of the new N elements corresponds to the sum of the numbers before it in the array.
>   In main, print the content of the array returned by the function.

It's OK also all in the `main` function.

I have the problem when I have to use the function `realloc` to increment the array from size = 5 to 5 + N.

This is my code:

```
int N, a, i;
int *ptr;
int arr[6];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Insert number in array, position(%d): ", i);
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}

N = arr[4];

a = 5 + N;

ptr = (int *)realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * a);

for (i = 4; i < a; i++) {
    ptr + i = N * N; //<--- **problem!!**
}

for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);
}

free(ptr);
```

Comment: You cannot `realloc`ate the size of an array. The array identifier, which decays to a pointer, was not obtained from `malloc`.

Comment: The loop reads the first 5 numbers using `scanf`. You then need a `scanf` after the loop to read `N`. And then there are more things to fix, but get one thing working at a time. I find that it's helpful to read the user's input, and then print it out, just to prove that all of the input was read correctly.

Comment: The indicated `ptr + i = N*N;` can't be compiled. Did you mean `*(ptr + i) = N*N`?

Comment: Instead of `ptr + i = N * N;`, as an alternate to what WeatherVane suggested [which will work], you could do `ptr[i] = N * N;`, which is equivalent, but more compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reallocate an array defined locally in a function nor defined globally. You can only call `realloc` on an object previously allocated with `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` or with a `NULL` pointer. So you must allocate the initial array with 5 elements in `main()` and reallocate it in the function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *extend_array(int *arr, int N) {
    int a = 5 + N;
    arr = realloc(arr, a * sizeof(int));
    if (arr != NULL) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 5; i < a; i++) {
            arr[i] = sum;
            sum += sum;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    int N;

    int *arr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Insert number in array, position(%d): ", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Insert the value of N: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int *ptr = extend_array(arr, N);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("reallocation failed\n");
    } else {
        arr = ptr;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 + N; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
        }
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The assignment specifies that the function should take the array and the number `N` as arguments, but it would be better to make the initial size a variable and pass that to the function as well to make the code more generic, easier to extend, and less error prone as the constant `5` appears in many places.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reallocate an array then it initially must be allocated dynamically.
So this code

```
int arr[6];
//...
ptr = (int *)realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * a);
```

is invalid.

Pay attention to that according to the assignment you need to write a function that reallocates the array.

Bear in mind that it is a very bad style of programming to use "magic numbers" like `5`. Instead use named constants or assign such numbers to variables and use them.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * resize( int *a, size_t n, size_t m )
{
    int *tmp = realloc( a, ( n + m ) * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        int sum = 0;
        size_t i = 0;

        while ( i < n ) sum += tmp[i++];
        while ( i < n + m )
        {
            tmp[i] = sum;
            sum += tmp[i++];
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 5;
    int *a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
    size_t m = 0;

    printf( "Enter %zu numbers. The last number shall be greater than 0: ", n + 1 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", a + i );
    }

    scanf( "%zu", &m );

    int *tmp  = resize( a, n, m );

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        a = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        m = 0;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n + m; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter 6 numbers. The last number shall be greater than 0: 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 15 30 60 120 240 480 960 1920 3840 7680
```